# Remove Text Around Tag

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a sql table with about 300 incorrectly formatted email messages that I am trying to clean up. I'm trying to retrieve all the email address so I can dump them in another table.

What I'd like to do is write a query that will remove all the text before and after the

```
 <Address />
```

tag. I would like for the following results to show up in my query:

```
       <Address id="ref-12">JohnDoe@MyWebSite.com</Address>
       <Address id="ref-12">JaneDoee@MyWebSite.com</Address>
        Etc..
```

Not sure how to really begin with this query or what to search for.

Comment: What does your source data look like?

Comment: I had to edit the text down in order to add to comments. The code before and after the address tags will not always be the same.<a1:SerialMailAddress id="ref-5" 
<Address id="ref-10">admin@mywebsite.com</Address>
<DisplayName xsi:null="1"/>
</a1:SerialMailAddress>
<a1:SerialMailAddress id="ref-8" 
<Address id="ref-11">jsmith@mywebsite.com</Address>
<DisplayName xsi:null="1"/>
</a1:SerialMailAddress>
<a1:SerialMailAddress id="ref-9" 
<Address id="ref-12">jdoe@mywebsite.com</Address>
<DisplayName xsi:null="1"/>
</a1:SerialMailAddress>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unclear on your question, but if you are trying to remove the tags around your emails then try this:

```
update table
set email = replace(email, '<Address id="ref-12">', '')
```

and then this:

```
update table
set email = replace(email, '</Address>', '')
```

Comment: or do it in one call... ```set email = replace(replace(email, '<Address id="ref-12">', ''), '</Address>', '')```

Comment: I want to keep the address tag in my query results. I have a lot of other extra text before the <Address id="ref-12"> and after the </Address> tag. A general replace will not accomplish this. Sorry I didn't make my question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     email = SUBSTRING(email, CHARINDEX('>', email) + 1,
                      LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('>', email) - 10) 
WHERE RIGHT(email,1) = '>'
```

Comment: nice, shame about the hard coded value for the closing tag (10). i guess this is fine for a one off query. here's the SQLFiddle in case anyone wants to see a break down of that substring call: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13770